# Modify a custom attribute of an Eloquent Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model which contain a custom attribute

```
class Test extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['counter'];
    public function getCounterAttribute()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I need to change the value of the custom attribute, like:

```
$tests = Test::all();
foreach ($tests AS $test) {
    $test->counter = $test->counter + 100;
}
```

This does not work, which is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your accessor returns always 1

```
public function getCounterAttribute()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Your loop sets correctly the `counter` attribute (inspectable via `$model->attributes['counter']`).
However, when you call `$test->counter` its value is resolved via the `getCounterAttribute()` method, that returns always 1.

Update your `getCounterAttribute()` to something like this:

```
public function getCounterAttribute()
{
    return isset($this->attributes['counter']) ? $this->attributes['counter'] : 1;
}
```

this way, you are saying: "if the counter attribute is set, return it. Otherwise, return 1".

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define a mutator on your Test model:

```
public function setCounterAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['counter'] = value;
}
```

For more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

Comment: the problem is not here. The mutator is not needed to change a value, even without the mutator you can set values on an eloquent model. The problem is in the getter, look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve same in Laravel 9 like so

```
protected function counter() : Attribute {
       return Attribute::make(
               get: fn ($value, $attributes) =>
                    ($attributes['counter']? $attributes['counter'] : 1)
       );
}
```